# Употребление фразеологизма "вытирать ноги"

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология, выбор-слов, этикет

Является ли фразеологическое выражение **вытирать ноги** оскорблением?
Мой вопрос касается употребления фразеологизма.

Answer (score 1):

Само по себе выражение оскорблением не является, однако в применении к собеседнику оно может быть излишне фамильярным (если упоминается третье лицо как источник действия, например: "он же вытер о тебя ноги" - в значении "унизил") и уместным лишь между близкими людьми при обсуждении неприятных ситуаций. Если же выражение использовано в форме угрозы ("теперь я буду вытирать о тебя ноги" и т. п.), то оно, действительно, становится оскорбительным.

Comment: Что-то сомнительная угроза...

Answer (score 1):

Оскорбле́ние — это умышленное унижение чести и достоинства личности, выраженное в неприличной форме ([Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

Все зависит от контекста. "Я вытираю о тебя ноги" – оскорбление. "Все вытирают о тебя ноги" (ты тряпка) – оскорбление. "Он вытирает о тебя ноги" – неоднозначно, может быть и добрым советом (обрати внимание на это и не позволяй так с собой обращаться), и завуалированным оскорблением типа "ты тряпка".

Answer (score 0):

**Вытирать ноги**
*о кого. Обл. Экспрес.* Унижать кого-либо; глумиться над кем-либо.
*— Да какие же у тебя, к дьяволу, грехи? Всю жизнь по тебе ходили, ноги вытирали, а ты — грехи* (Ф. Абрамов. Дом).
[**Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка**](https://phraseology.academic.ru/2187/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

**ВЫТЕРЕТЬ НОГИ**
*кто об кого*
Намеренно унижать.
Имеется в виду, что лицо или группа лиц совсем не считается с другим лицом или с другой группой лиц, уничижает их достоинство, всячески демонстрируя им своё превосходство и пренебрежение. Говорится с неодобрением.
[**Фразеологический словарь русского языка**](https://phrase_dictionary.academic.ru/544/%D0%92%D0%AB%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%A0%D0%95%D0%A2%D0%AC_%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%93%D0%98)

*Синонимы: **унижать, попирать, топтать, смешивать с грязью, втаптывать в грязь.***

Во втором словаре достаточно примеров употребления фразеологизма.
Я предоставлю другие, которые объединены *категорией **унижение***:

*Не стелись — не вытрут ноги.

Ноги надо об коврик вытирать, а не об людей.

Вытирая ноги о других, для приличия хотя бы руки помойте.*
*Когда перед тобой расстилаются тряпкой, просто не грех вытереть ноги.*

*Прежде чем нагло разбить чьё-то сердце, **вытереть ноги** о чьи-то чувства, помни: касса где-то впереди — за всё когда-нибудь придётся заплатить.*

*...вы что, никогда в жизни не ставили автомобиль на учёт, не оформляли в собственность квартиру, не пытались делать какие-то вещи, которые позволяют чиновникам **вытереть об вас ноги** за ваши же деньги?* (из интервью с А. Прохановым)

Является ли оскорблением? Само по себе — устное описание, использование в тексте, объяснение неприятной ситуации — нет.
А вот **действие** — да, безусловно, оскорбительно и унизительно.